# SharePoint Online addIn stuck in installation step

Tags: sharepoint-addin, error, deployment

A Sharepoint application got stuck in the installation step and has been "installing" since yesterday, about 18 hours. I cant run the application from Visual Studio. I get the following errors:
* Error occurred in deployment step 'Install Sharepoint Add-in'
* Skipping the uninstall step because the Sharepoint Add-in in in an invalid state and cannot be uninstalled

I'm using SharePoint online.
Tried upping the version number but then i still get the 'invalid state' error.

How can i force the application to stop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a know outage on this feature in Office 365 right now. You are probably being affected by it. https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1318

Comment: Yup, started working on some of the tenants I have tested on. So should probably be fixed for everyone soon

Comment: Yepp, seems like a fix is being slowly rolled out!

Comment: Had that problem yesterday. But it works now. This seems to be some other error